# consulta sql a una tabala con dos relaciones one-to-many

Tags: sql, symfony, relaciones

Requiero realizar una consulta a la base de datos en *Symfony*, tengo una *entity* que se llama *product_insumo*, la cual esta relacionada *one-to-many* con la tabla *product* e *insummo* y necesito realizar una consulta que me traiga todos los insumos que tiene en el mismo *product* y que me traiga sus respectivas cantidades.

```
 **entity Product**

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $precio;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $estado;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $ingreso;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ProductInsumo::class, mappedBy="Product")
     */
    private $productInsumos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->insumo = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->productInsumos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(string $nombre): self
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrecio(): ?float
    {
        return $this->precio;
    }

    public function setPrecio(float $precio): self
    {
        $this->precio = $precio;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEstado(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->estado;
    }

    public function setEstado(bool $estado): self
    {
        $this->estado = $estado;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIngreso(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->ingreso;
    }

    public function setIngreso(\DateTimeInterface $ingreso): self
    {
        $this->ingreso = $ingreso;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ProductInsumo[]
     */
    public function getProductInsumos(): Collection
    {
        return $this->productInsumos;
    }

    public function addProductInsumo(ProductInsumo $productInsumo): self
    {
        if (!$this->productInsumos->contains($productInsumo)) {
            $this->productInsumos[] = $productInsumo;
            $productInsumo->setProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProductInsumo(ProductInsumo $productInsumo): self
    {
        if ($this->productInsumos->contains($productInsumo)) {
            $this->productInsumos->removeElement($productInsumo);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($productInsumo->getProduct() === $this) {
                $productInsumo->setProduct(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

**entity Insumo**

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\InsumoRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=InsumoRepository::class)
 */
class Insumo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $cantidad;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $medida;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $estado;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $ingreso;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ProductInsumo::class, mappedBy="Insumo")
     */
    private $productInsumos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->productInsumos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNombre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function setNombre(string $nombre): self
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCantidad(): ?float
    {
        return $this->cantidad;
    }

    public function setCantidad(float $cantidad): self
    {
        $this->cantidad = $cantidad;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMedida(): ?string
    {
        return $this->medida;
    }

    public function setMedida(string $medida): self
    {
        $this->medida = $medida;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEstado(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->estado;
    }

    public function setEstado(bool $estado): self
    {
        $this->estado = $estado;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIngreso(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->ingreso;
    }

    public function setIngreso(\DateTimeInterface $ingreso): self
    {
        $this->ingreso = $ingreso;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ProductInsumo[]
     */
    public function getProductInsumos(): Collection
    {
        return $this->productInsumos;
    }

    public function addProductInsumo(ProductInsumo $productInsumo): self
    {
        if (!$this->productInsumos->contains($productInsumo)) {
            $this->productInsumos[] = $productInsumo;
            $productInsumo->setInsumo($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProductInsumo(ProductInsumo $productInsumo): self
    {
        if ($this->productInsumos->contains($productInsumo)) {
            $this->productInsumos->removeElement($productInsumo);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($productInsumo->getInsumo() === $this) {
                $productInsumo->setInsumo(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

**entity Product_insumo**

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProductInsumoRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductInsumoRepository::class)
 */
class ProductInsumo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Product::class, inversedBy="ProductInsumos")
     */
    private $Product;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Insumo::class, inversedBy="ProductInsumos")
     */
    private $insumo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $cantidad;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getProduct(): ?Product
    {
        return $this->Product;
    }

    public function setProduct(?Product $Product): self
    {
        $this->Product = $Product;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInsumo(): ?Insumo
    {
        return $this->insumo;
    }

    public function setInsumo(?Insumo $insumo): self
    {
        $this->insumo = $insumo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCantidad(): ?float
    {
        return $this->cantidad;
    }

    public function setCantidad(float $cantidad): self
    {
        $this->cantidad = $cantidad;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Hola! Puedes subir lo que fuiste armando de tu consulta o el repositorio, para ir dandote una mano con eso.

Comment: el repositorio esta como lo crea symfony.

Comment: el repositorio esta como lo crea symfony. tengo es la consulta en my sql que al ejecutarla en my phpmyadmin me funciona, la consulta es: SELECT `product_id`, `insumo_id`, `cantidad` FROM `product_insumo` WHERE `product_id`=1, pero al pasarla a symfony no me funciona, me dice que el product_id no existe o no esta iniciado.

Answer (score 1):

Si las entidades están bien formadas y enlazadas. Es tan simple como hacer un find de la entidad producto, pasándole el id. Te debería de devolver un objeto de la entidad Product con todos su atributos y entidades relacionadas.

```
 public function ejemplo(EntityManagerInterface $entity) {

    $this->entityManager = $entity;
    $productEntity = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Product::class)->find($id);
}
```

Pero para obtener todos los atributos de las entidades relacionadas tienes dos opciones :

1. Instanciar o inyectar por dependecia el componente Serializer. Por lo que solo tendrías que hacer un normalize o serialize, según como quieras obtener el resultado, si un array o un json. [Aquí tienes más información sobre ese componente](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

2. O la opción de implementar en todas la entidades la interfaces **JsonSerializable**

De manera que en la función que implementa esa interfaces, podrías tener algo como esto :

```
class Product implements \JsonSerializable {

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->getId(),
        'nombre' => $this->getNombre(),
        'insumos' => $this->getProductInsumos()
        ...
    ];
}}
```

Y en la clase Insumo

```
class Insumo implements \JsonSerializable {

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->getId(),
        'nombre' => $this->getNombre(),
        'cantidad' => $this->getCantidad()
        ...
    ];
}}
```

Ya solo tienes que devolver :

```
 return new JsonResponse($productEntity);
```

Comment: no mira tengo es la consulta en my sql que al ejecutarla en my phpmyadmin me funciona, la consulta es: SELECT `product_id`, `insumo_id`, `cantidad` FROM `product_insumo` WHERE `product_id`=1, pero al pasarla a symfony no me funciona, me dice que el product_id no existe o no esta iniciado.

Comment: Vale prueba hacer esto : 
1 - `$product = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Product::class)->find($id);`    
2 - `$productInsumo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(ProductInsumo::class)->findBy(['Product' => $product])`.

En el 1 me traigo el producto, y en el 2 busco todos los products_insumos por el producto encontrado en el primer paso.